# Carousel Card is not working well in BotFramework for Facebook Messenger

Tags: c#, carousel, botframework, facebook-messenger-bot

I have implemented a bot which sends a hero card to the user as a response.
As I have expected the following code send a carousel to the messenger.

```
ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));

#region HeroCard
Activity replyToConversation = activity.CreateReply("Should go to conversation, with a hero card");
replyToConversation.Recipient = activity.From;
replyToConversation.Type = "message";
replyToConversation.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
List<CardImage> cardImages = new List<CardImage>();
cardImages.Add(new CardImage(url: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a6/Bender_Rodriguez.png"));
cardImages.Add(new CardImage(url: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/archive/a/a9/20151112035044!Banyan_Tree_(_Shiv_Bajrang_Dham_Kishunpur).jpeg"));
List<CardAction> cardButtons = new List<CardAction>();
CardAction plButton = new CardAction()
{
    Value = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin",
    Type = "openUrl",
    Title = "WikiPedia Page"
};
CardAction plButton2 = new CardAction()
{
    Value = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin",
    Type = "openUrl",
    Title = "WikiPedia Page"
};
cardButtons.Add(plButton);
cardButtons.Add(plButton2);
HeroCard plCard = new HeroCard()
{
    Title = "I'm a hero card",
    Subtitle = "Pig Latin Wikipedia Page",
    Images = cardImages,
    Buttons = cardButtons
};
Attachment plAttachment = plCard.ToAttachment();
replyToConversation.Attachments.Add(plAttachment);
var reply = await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(replyToConversation);
#endregion
```

However, I got the following message which was not a carousel. 
[image]

The question is how can I send a carousel using the native variables of botframework (not using manual generated json) to Facebook Messenger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was solved by these changes:

- First, create two cards and attachments
- Second, set `AttachmentLayout` to `"carousel"`.

You can find the modified code in the following:

```
ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));

#region HeroCard

Activity replyToConversation = activity.CreateReply("Should go to conversation, with a hero card");
replyToConversation.Recipient = activity.From;
replyToConversation.Type = "message";
replyToConversation.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
// First Change
// Card #One
List<CardImage> cardImages1 = new List<CardImage>();
cardImages1.Add(new CardImage(url: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a6/Bender_Rodriguez.png"));

List<CardAction> cardButtons1 = new List<CardAction>();
CardAction plButton1 = new CardAction()
{
    Value = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin",
    Type = "openUrl",
    Title = "WikiPedia Page"
};
cardButtons1.Add(plButton1);
HeroCard plCard1 = new HeroCard()
{
    Title = "I'm a hero card",
    Subtitle = "Pig Latin Wikipedia Page",
    Images = cardImages1,
    Buttons = cardButtons1
};
Attachment plAttachment1 = plCard1.ToAttachment();
replyToConversation.Attachments.Add(plAttachment1);

// Card #Two
List<CardImage> cardImages2 = new List<CardImage>();
cardImages2.Add(new CardImage(url: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/archive/a/a9/20151112035044!Banyan_Tree_(_Shiv_Bajrang_Dham_Kishunpur).jpeg"));

List<CardAction> cardButtons2 = new List<CardAction>();
CardAction plButton2 = new CardAction()
{
    Value = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin",
    Type = "openUrl",
    Title = "WikiPedia Page"
};
cardButtons2.Add(plButton2);
HeroCard plCard2 = new HeroCard()
{
    Title = "I'm a hero card",
    Subtitle = "Pig Latin Wikipedia Page",
    Images = cardImages2,
    Buttons = cardButtons2
};

Attachment plAttachment2 = plCard2.ToAttachment();
replyToConversation.Attachments.Add(plAttachment2);

// Second Change
replyToConversation.AttachmentLayout = "carousel";

var reply = await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(replyToConversation);
#endregion
```

you can find the image of the carousel in Facebook Messenger in the below:
[image]